# JPQL createQuery throws illegalArgumentException

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb, jpql

The following simple code throws exception:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Customer c");
```

But if I write

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT c.* FROM Customer c", Customer.class)
```

then it works without any error. What might be wrong? I use GlassFish v2.1 with Toplink-essentials.

Comment: Could you add the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JPQL query "SELECT c FROM Customer c" is valid as long as you have a class Customer defined as an Entity. That method only throws an Exception if the query is "invalid" for some reason, and any decent JPA implementation should give more information in the message of the exception if there is some problem

--Andy ([DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org))

Comment: Thank you Andy. I have Customer class with @Entity annotation. As I said native query returns customer objects without any problem, but ordinary jpa query doesn't work.

Comment: So I suggest that either you use the TopLink log and mailing list, or you try other JPA implementations (e.g DataNucleus) that certainly do support such syntax.

Comment: Ok, Andy you were right. I used table name instead of class name. Actually my query was "SELECT c FROM customer_info c".